# Comparison of texts of a jtextfield with an autocompletion

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I would like to know if there is a way to have a text validator, not the equals exactly, because I know if I do one by one it would take me a lifetime, but to validate all the autocompletion that I did to the jtextfield, I add text to see if they can help me.

```
import com.mxrck.autocompleter.TextAutoCompleter;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Comparativa extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public TextAutoCompleter ac;
        public Comparativa(){
        ac = new TextAutoCompleter(jTextfield);
        ac.addItem("Procesador");
        ac.addItem("RAM");
        ac.addItem("Disco");
    }

    public void ValidadorComparacion(){
        if(jTextfield.getText().equals(ac.getItem)){
            System.out.println("GOOD");
        }else{
            System.out.println("BAD");
        }
    }
```

In the final part I want to make it compare if or if the code but I don't want to use "equals" for each item , but for everything.
That code gives me an error in the `.equals` part.

Comment: "_That code gives me an error_" - You can [edit] the question and add the error message you are getting (as formatted text).

Comment: People may also need to understand how `com.mxrck.autocompleter.TextAutoCompleter` works. Where did you get this library? What you need may be as simple as using `ArrayList.contains("...");`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you are actually getting but you should check the value of `jTextField` to be non-null.

```
public void ValidadorComparacion(){
    if (jTextField.getText() != null && jTextfield.getText().equals(ac.getItem())){
        System.out.println("GOOD");
    }else{
        System.out.println("BAD");
    }
  }
```

If you get an error during compilation, please provide more of your source code. **And** the exact error message.

Comment: What happens is that it doesn't make the comparison, that's the bad thing, since I have a list I want it to be compared directly with the "ac"